# Java Invisible whitespace in the beginnig of the String

Tags: java, string

I want to read a String from a file. String contains several floating numbers separated with whitespace. Then I want to split it into several Strings, containing one number each and parse them to double. numbers.length() shows that my String is 1 symbol longer than it actualy is in the file. And this symbol is an invisible whitespace I cant get rid of. First element in the array has it too, and trim() doesnt help. I tried to trim every element in array, doesnt help. I cant parse this array into numbers because of this whitespace, Im getting an exception. I see that this is actualy a whitespace in the beginning only if I split String numbers or the first element of the array into chars. Beginner programmer here.

```
    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String file1 = reader1.readLine();
    reader1.close();

    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
    String numbers = reader2.readLine();
    reader2.close();
    System.out.println(numbers.length());

    String[] array = numbers.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Just because it's invisible, doesn't mean it's going to match `\s` (because `\s` [is not "white space"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), it's "the regular expression whitespace class, matching the following character(groups): `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`"), so: what is the _actual string_, and because the invisible text is invisible, which unicode points are they?

Comment: It's just my test.txt file from the Windows desktop. It looks like:                      4234.234 2341.452 98234.4 2378.34 114.32

Comment: Prove it (and not even to us, but to yourself): load it in, and then print out what the actual charCode values are.

Comment: Can you show us the first line of the file? Have you tried using an editor that will show non-visible characters?

Comment: Full code, pictures of input and output ara in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[First Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xel4b.png)  [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN3eu.png)   Full code of the class. And I added what I get in IDEA. That whitespace or whatever that goes before '4' in printing array[0] is my problem.

41
4234.234 9
2341.452 8
98234.4 7
2378.34 7
114.32 6

4
2
3
4
.
2
3
4

Process finished with exit code 0

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String file1 = reader1.readLine();
    reader1.close();

    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
    String numbers = reader2.readLine();
    reader2.close();
    System.out.println(numbers.length());

    String[] array = numbers.trim().split("\\s+");

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i] + " " + array[i].length());
    }
    char[] ch = array[0].toCharArray();
    for(char c:ch) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It adds everything in one line here...I added a picture of the output.